# c++ read a text file, display similarly

Tags: c++, text-files, path-finding

Firstly, please forgive me, my coding knowledge is poor at best.
I've read a number of guides and for the life of me cannot work this out.

I was playing around with code previously featured on this site, as shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue> 

using namespace std;

class CNode
{
public:

CNode() : xPos(0), yPos(0), travelCost(0) {}
CNode(int x, int y) : xPos(x), yPos(y), travelCost(0) {}
CNode(int x, int y, int cost) : xPos(x), yPos(y), travelCost(cost) {}

inline CNode& operator=(const CNode& target)
{
    if (*this != target)
    {
        xPos = target.xPos;
        yPos = target.yPos;
        travelCost = target.travelCost;
    }

    return *this;
}

inline bool operator==(const CNode& target) const
{
    return xPos == target.xPos && yPos == target.yPos;
}

inline bool operator!=(const CNode& target) const
{
    return !(*this == target);
}

inline bool operator<(const CNode& target) const
{
    return target.travelCost < travelCost;
}

int xPos, yPos, travelCost;
};

class CPath
{
public:

typedef vector<CNode> nodeList;

nodeList Find(const CNode& startNode, const CNode& endNode, int mapArray[][20])
{
    nodeList finalPath, openList, closedList;

    finalPath.push_back(startNode);
    openList.push_back(startNode);
    closedList.push_back(startNode);

    while (!openList.empty())
    {
        // Check each node in the open list
        for (size_t i = 0; i < openList.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (openList[i].xPos == endNode.xPos && openList[i].yPos == endNode.yPos)
                return finalPath;

            priority_queue<CNode> nodeQueue;

            // Get surrounding nodes
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
                {
                    const int current_x = openList[i].xPos + x;
                    const int current_y = openList[i].yPos + y;

                    bool alreadyCheckedNode = false;
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < closedList.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        if (current_x == closedList[i].xPos && current_y == closedList[i].yPos)
                        {
                            alreadyCheckedNode = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (alreadyCheckedNode)
                        continue;

                    // Ignore current coordinate and don't go out of array scope
                    if (current_x < 0 || current_x > 20 || current_y < 0 ||current_y > 20 || (openList[i].xPos == current_x && openList[i].yPos == current_y))
                        continue;

                    // Ignore walls
                    if (mapArray[current_x][current_y] == '#')
                        continue;

                    const int xNodeDifference = abs(current_x - (openList[i].xPos));
                    const int yNodeDifference = abs(current_y - (openList[i].yPos));            

                    // Diagonal?
                    const int direction = xNodeDifference == 1 && yNodeDifference == 1 ? 14 : 10;

                    const int xDistance = abs(current_x - endNode.xPos);
                    const int yDistance = abs(current_y - endNode.yPos);
                    int heuristic = 10 * (xDistance + yDistance);

                    nodeQueue.push(CNode(current_x, current_y, heuristic));
                }
            }

            if (!nodeQueue.empty())
            {
                // Add the nearest node
                openList.push_back(nodeQueue.top());
                finalPath.push_back(nodeQueue.top());

                // Put into closed list
                while (!nodeQueue.empty())
                {
                    closedList.push_back(nodeQueue.top());
                    nodeQueue.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return finalPath;
}
};

int mapArray[20][20] =
{
{ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
{ '#', 'A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#' },
{ '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B', '#' },
{ '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
CNode start, end;

for (int width = 0; width < 20; ++width)
{
    for (int height = 0; height < 20; ++height)
    {
        if (mapArray[width][height] == 'A')
        {
            start.xPos = width;
            start.yPos = height;
        }
        else if (mapArray[width][height] == 'B')
        {
            end.xPos = width;
            end.yPos = height;
        }
    }
}

CPath pathFinder;
CPath::nodeList n = pathFinder.Find(start, end, mapArray);

for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i)
    if (mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] != 'A' && mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] != 'B')
        mapArray[n[i].xPos][n[i].yPos] = '*';

for (int height = 0; height < 20; ++height)
{
    for (int width = 0; width < 20; ++width)
    {
        if (width % 20 == 0)
            cout << endl;

        cout << (char)mapArray[height][width] << " ";
    }
}

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

The issue is this: there is a predefined 'map', done by physically inputting '#'s for walls, '  's for walkable spaces, etc. 
Instead, I would like to have the program read in a .txt file (made of 0's and 1's - 0 for walkable, 1 for a wall) and create this map automatically.

How would I go about this?
Could you please show me?

edit:
A sample of data in the .txt files are as follows:
10001101
11000001
10000100
10010001

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Reading the file, filling the data structures, or displaying the results?

Comment: Shamefully - all of the above to be quite honest.

Comment: Please post a snippet of the data format in the text file.

Comment: It is simply a file containing 1's and 0's set out in a matrix-like shape, ie.   
1101000   
0001000   
0000000

Comment: Just use a 2D array or char. Read each line of the file using GetLine and then for each character if its a 1 add a '#' to the correct position in the array, otherwise set to ' ' and that's it. Then just use std::cout to print out each char in the array from top to bottom (adding std::endl to the end of each row).

Comment: Would you consider using `vector<vector<int> >` instead of `int[][]`?